# Change color of point lights automatically over time

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using a gradient script to change the color of a sphere over time, but I want a point light associated to it to change too.

The script I'm using is this:

```
public class gradient : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Gradient myGradient;
    public float strobeDuration = 2f;

    public void Update()
    {
        float t = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / strobeDuration, 1f);
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color= myGradient.Evaluate(t);
    }
}
```

The light object accepts the script but it doesn't affect the color.

I assume it's because this script is associated to materials and light has no material...

Comment: Your assumption sounds sensible. So, based on that assumption, you tried modifying the script to get the `Light` component instead of the `Renderer` component, and assign the light's colour that way?

Comment: You can usually find answers to this type of questions by doing a web search for things like '[unity change color of light from code](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+change+color+of+light+from+code)'.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i asjed here after searching in tutorials on utube and in this forum for similar questions but dont seem to find the right answer. Any ways i will keep looking, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your light's color isn't changing because it uses the `Light` component, not `Renderer`. Simply add support for the `Light` component:

```
if (TryGetComponent(out Light light))
    light.color = myGradient.Evaluate(t);
```

With that said, I'd recommend that you use `TryGetComponent` for working with the `Renderer` component too:

```
if (TryGetComponent(out Renderer renderer))
    renderer.material.color = myGradient.Evaluate(t);
```

The use of `TryGetComponent` will help prevent potential `NullReferenceException`s from occurring.